# I want to change the value of a variable(not local variable) inside a python method? Please check the code below

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop, global-variables

In the code below, I was getting this.

```
NameError: name 'digitsum' is not defined
```

Please note that we can return values but that's not I want exactly here. I just want to change the **outside values** inside function `f`.

```
class Solution:
    def compute(n) -> int:
        digitsum = 0

        def f(k):
            global digitsum
            if k==0:
                return
            digitsum+=k%10
            f(k//10)

        f(3648)
        return digitsum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `digitsum` is not a global variable, which is why you're getting a `NameError`.  In this particular case what you want instead is `nonlocal`.

A simplified example:

```py
>>> def foo():
...     x = 0
...     def f():
...         nonlocal x
...         x += 1
...     f()
...     print(x)
... 
>>> foo()
1
```

Comment: Best answer among all.

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA Glad it helped.  If so, please be so kind as to upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    digitsum = 0
    def compute(self,n) -> int:
        self.digitsum = 0
        def f(k):
            
            if k==0:
                return
            self.digitsum+=k%10
            f(k//10)

        f(n)
        return self.digitsum
    
    
Solution().compute(45)
```

Comment: Please explain what are the changes. That helps people learn better